# SQLAlchemy ORM adjust SQL syntax for MutableList/Array

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, databricks

I'm using MutableList to store a python list in a SQL array as described [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/mutable.html):

```
class MyMutableList(MutableList):
    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, key, value):
        """Convert plain lists to MutableList."""
        if not isinstance(value, MutableList):
            if isinstance(value, list):
                return MutableList(value)

            return MutableList(json.loads(value))
        else:
            return value
```

model.py:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"

    bar = Column(MyMutableList.as_mutable(ARRAY(String(64))))
```

Reading the SQL array works fine.  When writing (insert/update) SQLAlchemy uses this syntax:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar=['36','42'];
```

But the dialect that I'm using (*databricks+pyodbc*, *Simba*) needs this syntax:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar=ARRAY('36','42');
```

Is there a generic way of adjusting this in ORM SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working with the following workaround:

```
def get_sql_insert(self):
"""Return SQL syntax for creating the current object."""

update = f"INSERT INTO {self.__tablename__}"
vars = []
values = []
for attr, value in dict(self).items():
    vars.append(attr)
    # set default if applicable
    column = self.__table__.c[attr]
    if value is None and column.default is not None:
        if column.default.is_scalar:
            value = column.default.arg
        else:
            value = column.default.arg("")

    if isinstance(value, list):
        values.append(f"ARRAY({','.join([repr(v) for v in value])})")
    elif isinstance(value, datetime):
        values.append(repr(str(value)))
    else:
        values.append(repr(value))
```

Still hoping to find a more adequate solution here...